# How to Upload pics on an existing post

Tags: support

How do I upload pics on My current post? What size do the pics have to be?
I had asked a question about my willow tree, and responses are asking for a photo. I have searched everywhere and don't see where there is an "uload image" anywheres. Please help, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Until you get 10 rep you cannot upload pictures to your post. (you can however host them somewhere else and add a link to them)

However, when you do There is a button in the post formatting bar above the text entry box with a little picture in it. From there you can upload your photo and it will inline it for you.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to upload 1 pic, but can I upload more on same post to show better shot of the issue?

Comment: @2Bleu-zone7b same process (I'm honestly not sure if there is another rep limitation on number of images/links you're allowed to post, but there is a good chance that there is)

Comment: Okay, thanks. Everyone's been so helpful here. :)